# Generic factory method in Spring DI

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I wonder why in Spring DI the following bean definition works (I use [bean instantiation with a static factory method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method) and Guava's [`Suppliers.ofInstance`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.html#ofInstance%28T%29)):

```xml
<bean id="keySupplier" class="com.google.common.base.Suppliers"
    factory-method="ofInstance">
  <constructor-arg>
    <value type="java.lang.String">someReallyLongValue <!-- note line break here -->
    </value>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

but this one doesn't:

```xml
<bean id="keySupplier" class="com.google.common.base.Suppliers"
    factory-method="ofInstance">
  <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="someReallyLongValue" />
</bean>
```

It throws following exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepo' defined in class path resource:
>   (...)
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.Object]:
>   Ambiguous factory method argument types - did you specify the correct bean references as factory method arguments?

The problem is, in my case, when I use first bean definition with really long string as a value my editor breaks line after last character of string, which causes that **string is passed with additional whitespace** to `Suppliers.ofInstance` and in result it breaks my code.

The second definition would be more strict about whitespace but, suprisingly, it doesn't work (it probably doesn't cope with generic type, despite the type is specified in type attribute).

Can I force Spring to ignore whitespace in `<value>` tag somehow?

Or do I use `<constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="someReallyLongValue" />` properly? Or should I file an issue because it's a Spring bug?

I'd rather not make any assumptions about the string (i.e. use `string.trim()` here).

Comment: First, configure your XML editor to no insert line breaks automatically. If there is no such option, change editor ;)

Comment: @YvesMartin I can configure my editor to do so but if someone else in the future does the formatting (simple `C-S-f` in Eclipse), I don't like the fact that application will be broken because of that.

Comment: Such issue will always exist. You should move such text information to properties file.

Answer (score 6):

The two configurations do not involve the same execution path in Spring according to [reference documentation about constructor resolution](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/reference/beans.html#d0e746). The failure comes from generics used for [this instanceOf method](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/11.0/com/google/common/base/Suppliers.java#Suppliers.ofInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) which declares `Object` as method argument.

Spring has to do the following tasks to succeed:

- find the right method according to arguments
- convert XML literal values into Java objects either thanks to explicit `type` declaration or based on method argument types when `index` is used

The logic involved is in [ConstructorArgumentValues](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/spring/spring-3.0.5/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConstructorArgumentValues.java.html) holder in the method `getArgumentValue` and in both `getIndexedArgumentValue` and `getGenericArgumentValue`. Both methods use tests to reject a `ValueHolder` based on information available.

In the second configuration scenario, the indexed detection is used and rejects the value because the required type `String` does not match exactly with `Object`. This test is done with [`ClassUtils.matchesTypeName`](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/spring/spring-3.0.5/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.java.html) which does not check the type hierarchy.

In the first configuration scenario, the value holder is ready with a `String` object and the generic argument mechanism agrees because the value is assignable to the detected method argument type.

Theoretically speaking, the following expression should work because type is provided to generate the object from the value and index is provided to avoid any guessing, even if there is only one method matching.

```
   <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="queueName" />
```

Bad luck, it does not improve anything, the same execution path is still used. I really think a Spring improvement is required. May you create a [JIRA ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa).

Comment: Is the difference between `<constructor-arg value="" />` and `<constructor-arg><value /></constructor-arg>` documented somewhere or did you check the source code?

Comment: I've created [a ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9270), now I'll wait if the bug is confirmed.

Comment: I do not consider it as a bug but as a improvement. By the way, the recommended form to do this configuration is the use of "<value>" tag !

Comment: I've debugged this and seems that you're right about the casue - a condition checking `ClassUtils.matchesTypeName` called with String type and generic method's type (T treated as Object) causes bean creation failure in the end.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use a properties file and then use the property in the definition

*But this does not explain your observed behaviour.*

Comment: Actually I've chosen `Supplier<String>` not `String` as a dependency because I am going to do more advanced stuff with Supplier (memoize supplied value, get String from registry / property file etc.). This concrete case is kind of mock implementation of `keySupplier` bean and that's why I used `Suppliers.ofInstance` static factory here and why I'm curious about the bean creation failure.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but try

```
  <value index="0" [...]
```

Not sure what your code looks like but the order that you place your constructor args is not considered unless you specify the location. If you have multiple constructors this can mess things up.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't help here - got same exception. BTW you meant  `<constructor-arg index="0" (...) />`, right?